# During hover on parent element, show child (dropdown nav)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm trying to make a stupid horizontal nav bar with a drop-down on some of the items.  The way I decided to do it is just by putting the drop-down in a div tag.  This is easily changeable, i just don't like to go heavy on the html side.

Basically I just want my drop down to work when you hover over the parent element. Additional css is going to be used to make it pretty and positioned better.

Here's my js:

```
var dropdown = $('.dropdown');
var parent = dropdown.parent();
$(parent).hover(
    function () {
        dropdown.css('display', 'block');
    }
);
```

Here's my css:

```
div.nav {
    text-align: center;
}
div.nav > ul > li {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
div.nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.nav a {
    padding: 1em;
}
div.dropdown {
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="game.html">Sample Game</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="index.html">About it</a>
                <br>
                <a href="index.html">Game</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html">TP Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: i know, i actually had it working with css, but since I have to size the children elements to be the same size as the parent I wanted to switch it over to js.  I couldn't figure out the sizing in css without hardcoding it and width = 100% didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using "parent" as a variable name, as it's a reserved word.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
        $parent = $dropdown.parent();
    $parent.on("mouseover",
        function () {
            $dropdown.css('display', 'block');
        }
    );
    $parent.on("mouseout",
        function () {
            $dropdown.css('display', 'none');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: whats the difference between mouseove and hover?

Comment: @Tmp See if you are using jquery version `1.9` then don't use `.hover`

Comment: i tried both, but it isn't working. im also using the latest version

Comment: No real difference in this case but notice that you were using $(parent), which is wrong because "parent" was already a jquery object.

Comment: Did you change the variable names?

Comment: yeah, changed parent to parentD, and also using $

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. Are you sure you're not calling JS before your DOM has loaded?

Comment: just made an edit to my answer to make sure that it's run after DOM has loaded

Comment: very peculiar... it works now, but the other answer works too without waiting for the DOM to load

Comment: @Jai and petermk only problem with your answers is that it doesn't go away after you stop hovering

Comment: You should add an onmouseout event to make it go away

Answer (score 1):

According to the oreder this has to be done:

- add a jQuery plugin first
- Then add your script

so the order will be like this:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script>
   $(function(){
      var dropdown = $('.dropdown');
      var parent = dropdown.parent();
      $(parent).hover(function () {
         dropdown.css('display', 'block');
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't include that portion of the code, but i import the jquery first.  Your code seems to work for me though, thanks! don't really know why...

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.

```
    $(".nav").on("mouseenter","li",function(){
        $(this).find(".dropdown").show();
    });
    $(".nav").on("mouseleave","li",function(){
        $(this).find(".dropdown").hide();
    });
```

In your code " dropdown.parent(); " -> this will refer all the parents which have child dropdown and will show the menu. we need to refer current hover parent. Please check the working example in below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/renjith/wX48f/

Answer (score 0):

There are so many good solutions to use jQuery and CSS to show a drop down menus. So you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Here are some [examples](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) that you might be able to find one to fit your need.

Comment: what if some people actually want to learn instead of blindly copying someone else's code?

Comment: agree. but some examples are very simple. So themselves can be used as good tutorials. Take a look at this [one](http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw) and you will see what I mean. :)

Comment: i did borrow a simple css solution, but this js is simple and should work