# How would I make this CSS / jQuery dropdown menu multilevel?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this dropdown menu multilevel. Here is the codepen of it: http://codepen.io/owlsky/pen/DduKj

I'm trying to learn how to get this menu to open an additional menu when the user hovers over one of the options. I'm not very comfortable with JQuery, so hopefully the solution is somewhat easy to understand.

HTML:

```
<select name="" id="" class="dropdown">
  <option class="label">Label</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="1">option 2</option>
  <option value="1">option 3</option>
  <option value="1">option 4</option>
  <option value="1">option 5</option>
  <option value="1">option 6</option>
  <option value="1">option 7</option>
  <option value="1">option 8</option>
  <option value="1">option 9</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
/* reset */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* --- EASYDROPDOWN DEFAULT THEME --- */

/* PREFIXED CSS */

.dropdown,
.dropdown div,
.dropdown li,
.dropdown div::after{
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .selected::after,
.dropdown.scrollable div::after{
    -webkit-pointer-events: none;
    -moz-pointer-events: none;
    -ms-pointer-events: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* WRAPPER */

.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;

    border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.dropdown.open{
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.dropdown.focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(51,102,248,.4);
}

/* CARAT */

.dropdown .carat{
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #000;
}

.dropdown.open .carat{
    margin-top: -10px;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
}

/* OLD SELECT (HIDDEN) */

.dropdown .old{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown select{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.dropdown.touch .old{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.dropdown.touch select{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* SELECTED FEEDBACK ITEM */ 

.dropdown .selected,
.dropdown li{
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    padding: 9px 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown .selected::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 60px;

    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    box-shadow: inset -55px 0 25px -20px #fff;
}

/* DROP DOWN WRAPPER */

.dropdown div{
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Height is adjusted by JS on open */

.dropdown.open div{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* FADE OVERLAY FOR SCROLLING LISTS */

.dropdown.scrollable div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;

    box-shadow: inset 0 -50px 30px -35px #fff;
}

.dropdown.scrollable.bottom div::after{
    opacity: 0;
}

/* DROP DOWN LIST */

.dropdown ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown.scrollable.open ul{
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* DROP DOWN LIST ITEMS */

.dropdown li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}

/* .focus class is also added on hover */

.dropdown li.focus{
    background: #d24a67;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown li.active{
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

JS:

```
/*
* EASYDROPDOWN - A Drop-down Builder for Styleable Inputs and Menus
* Version: 2.0.4
* License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported - CC BY 3.0
* http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
* This software may be used freely on commercial and non-commercial projects with attribution to the author/copyright holder.
* Author: Patrick Kunka
* Copyright 2013 Patrick Kunka, All Rights Reserved
*/

(function(d){function e(){this.isField=!0;this.keyboardMode=this.hasLabel=this.cutOff=this.inFocus=this.down=!1;this.nativeTouch=!0;this.wrapperClass="dropdown";this.onSelect=null}function f(a,c){var b=new e;b.init(a,c);b.instances.push(b)}e.prototype={constructor:e,instances:[],init:function(a,c){var b=this;d.extend(b,c);b.$select=d(a);b.options=[];b.$options=b.$select.find("option");b.isTouch="ontouchend"in document;b.$select.removeClass(b.wrapperClass+" dropdown");b.$options.length&&(b.$options.each(function(a){var c=
d(this);c.is(":selected")&&(b.selected={index:a,title:c.text()},b.focusIndex=a);c.hasClass("label")&&0==a?(b.hasLabel=!0,b.label=c.text(),c.attr("value","")):b.options.push({domNode:c[0],title:c.text(),value:c.val(),selected:c.is(":selected")})}),b.selected||(b.selected={index:0,title:b.$options.eq(0).text()},b.focusIndex=0),b.render())},render:function(){var a=this;a.$container=a.$select.wrap('<div class="'+a.wrapperClass+(a.isTouch&&a.nativeTouch?" touch":"")+'"><span class="old"/></div>').parent().parent();
a.$active=d('<span class="selected">'+a.selected.title+"</span>").appendTo(a.$container);a.$carat=d('<span class="carat"/>').appendTo(a.$container);a.$scrollWrapper=d("<div><ul/></div>").appendTo(a.$container);a.$dropDown=a.$scrollWrapper.find("ul");a.$form=a.$container.closest("form");d.each(a.options,function(){a.$dropDown.append("<li"+(this.selected?' class="active"':"")+">"+this.title+"</li>")});a.$items=a.$dropDown.find("li");a.maxHeight=0;a.cutOff&&a.$items.length>a.cutOff&&a.$container.addClass("scrollable");
for(i=0;i<a.$items.length;i++){var c=a.$items.eq(i);a.maxHeight+=c.outerHeight();if(a.cutOff==i+1)break}a.isTouch&&a.nativeTouch?a.bindTouchHandlers():a.bindHandlers()},bindTouchHandlers:function(){var a=this;a.$container.on("click",function(){a.$select.focus()});a.$select.on({change:function(){var c=d(this).find("option:selected"),b=c.text(),c=c.val();a.$active.text(b);"function"==typeof a.onSelect&&a.onSelect.call(a,{title:b,value:c})},focus:function(){a.$container.addClass("focus")},blur:function(){a.$container.removeClass("focus")}})},
bindHandlers:function(){var a=this;a.query="";a.$container.on({click:function(){a.down?a.close():a.open()},mousemove:function(){a.keyboardMode&&(a.keyboardMode=!1)}});d("body").on("click",function(c){c=d(c.target);var b=a.wrapperClass.split(" ").join(".");!c.closest("."+b).length&&a.down&&a.close()});a.$items.on({click:function(){var c=d(this).index();a.select(c);a.$select.focus()},mouseover:function(){if(!a.keyboardMode){var c=d(this);c.addClass("focus").siblings().removeClass("focus");a.focusIndex=
c.index()}},mouseout:function(){a.keyboardMode||d(this).removeClass("focus")}});a.$select.on({focus:function(){a.$container.addClass("focus");a.inFocus=!0},blur:function(){a.$container.removeClass("focus");a.inFocus=!1}});a.$dropDown.on("scroll",function(c){a.$dropDown[0].scrollTop==a.$dropDown[0].scrollHeight-a.maxHeight?a.$container.addClass("bottom"):a.$container.removeClass("bottom")});a.$select.on("keydown",function(c){if(a.inFocus){a.keyboardMode=!0;var b=c.keyCode;if(38==b||40==b||32==b)c.preventDefault(),
38==b?(a.focusIndex--,a.focusIndex=0>a.focusIndex?a.$items.length-1:a.focusIndex):40==b&&(a.focusIndex++,a.focusIndex=a.focusIndex>a.$items.length-1?0:a.focusIndex),a.down||a.open(),a.$items.removeClass("focus").eq(a.focusIndex).addClass("focus"),a.cutOff&&a.scrollToView(),a.query="";if(a.down)if(9==b||27==b)a.close();else{if(13==b)return c.preventDefault(),a.select(a.focusIndex),a.close(),!1;if(8==b)return c.preventDefault(),a.query=a.query.slice(0,-1),a.search(),!1;38!=b&&40!=b&&(c=String.fromCharCode(b),
a.query+=c,a.search())}}});if(a.$form.length)a.$form.on("reset",function(){a.$active.text(a.hasLabel?a.label:"")})},open:function(){var a=window.scrollY||document.documentElement.scrollTop,c=window.scrollX||document.documentElement.scrollLeft,b=this.notInViewport(a);this.closeAll();this.$select.focus();window.scrollTo(c,a+b);this.$container.addClass("open");this.$scrollWrapper.css("height",this.maxHeight+"px");this.down=!0},close:function(){this.$container.removeClass("open");this.$scrollWrapper.css("height",
"0px");this.focusIndex=this.selected.index;this.query="";this.down=!1},closeAll:function(){var a=Object.getPrototypeOf(this).instances;for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)a[i].close()},select:function(a){var c=this.options[a],b=this.hasLabel?a+1:a;this.$items.removeClass("active").eq(a).addClass("active");this.$active.text(c.title);this.$select.find("option").prop("selected",!1).eq(b).prop("selected","selected");this.selected={index:a,title:c.title};this.focusIndex=i;"function"==typeof this.onSelect&&this.onSelect.call(this,
{title:c.title,value:c.value})},search:function(){for(i=0;i<this.options.length;i++)if(-1!=this.options[i].title.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.query)){this.focusIndex=i;this.$items.removeClass("focus").eq(this.focusIndex).addClass("focus");this.scrollToView();break}},scrollToView:function(){if(this.focusIndex>=this.cutOff){var a=this.$items.eq(this.focusIndex).outerHeight()*(this.focusIndex+1)-this.maxHeight;this.$dropDown.scrollTop(a)}},notInViewport:function(a){var c=a+(window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight),
b=this.$dropDown.offset().top+this.maxHeight;return b>=a&&b<=c?0:b-c+5}};d.fn.easyDropDown=function(a){return this.each(function(){f(this,a)})};d(function(){"function"!==typeof Object.getPrototypeOf&&(Object.getPrototypeOf="object"===typeof"test".__proto__?function(a){return a.__proto__}:function(a){return a.constructor.prototype});d(".dropdown").each(function(){var a=d(this).attr("data-settings");settings=a?d.parseJSON(a):{};f(this,settings)})})})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will be impossible with this plugin. Probably you have to choice another one or start learning jQuery ;-)

Comment: look on this post:

[dropdown-nav][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422199/during-hover-on-parent-element-show-child-dropdown-nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using EasyDropdown because it's not the original purpose of the plugin, even with [`optgroup`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag (2-level only).

But if [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-examples) is ok for you :3 I suggest you see the nested/multilevel dropdown example here:

- [show dropdown when hovered](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)
- [show dropdown when clicked](http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz) (good for mobile)